# Using backbone on node with 3rd party rest service

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I'm try to pull data from a restful service like say twitter.  I've done this before in the client with success.  Now I'm trying to do it on the server, I can't seem to get backbone to load properly.  When I require("backbone") and the file loads, "this" is the module but from the notes on line 15 of backbone.js, its expecting it too be "global"  Is there a special way to load this file that puts the global ref in "this"

Here is comments from backbone.js file (line 13-15)

```
  // Save a reference to the global object (`window` in the browser, `global`
  // on the server).
  var root = this;
```

But like I said before, it aint 'global', its just an empty [Object].  So, I see at least two possibilities.

1. load the backbone.js file in a way that sets "this" to global.  It this possible?
2. change the backbone.js file to "var root = global"

Is #1 possible?  Am I missing some possibilities?

thx,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using setDomLibrary function.

```
Backbone.setDomLibrary(require('jquery'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you install backbone like this:

```
npm install backbone
```

Comment: yup.  I think the problem is that "this" is actually module rather than global.